# How do I call a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I am currently done making a sokoban game with GUI and everything and I am working on optimzation, I would like to keep the objects as sensible as possible and therefore need to be able to call the constructor from a method in the class/object. Suppose:

```
public class BoardGame() {

public BoardGame)() {
this(1)
}

public BoardGame(int level){
//Do stuff, like calling filelevel-to-board loaderclass
}
```

How do I create a method that calls the constructor of this object/class in the object/class itself? Eg:

```
public BoardGame nextLevel() {
return BoardGame(currentLevel+1);
}
```

The above is apparently undefined!

Such that if I want to use this object in another class I should be able to do:

```
GameBoard sokoban = new GameBoard(); //lvl1
draw(GameBoard);
draw(GameBoard.nextLevel()); //draws lvl2
```

Comment: This is a tangent, but perhaps Level should be its own class, and GameBoard should contain a Level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword to call the constructor.

```
public BoardGame nextLevel() {
    return new BoardGame(currentLevel + 1);
}
```

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense ;) I was struggling with this for an hour and not something you can easily look up but should have thought of this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calling the constructor requires the `new` keyword and always creates a new instance. For instance, in your example code

```
GameBoard sokoban = new GameBoard(); //lvl1
draw(sokoban );
draw(sokoban.nextLevel()); //draws lvl2
sokoban <-- still level 1
```

Maybe you want the GameBoard to be mutable:

```
public class GameBoard {

    public GameBoard() {
        setLevel(1);
    }

    private void setLevel(int i) {
        currentLevel = i;
        ....
    }

    public void nextLevel() {
        setLevel(currentLevel+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not in its current implementation, the board is in a fixed array which is created from another class that loads the level from a .txt file.